# How to get Identity User from his authentication JWT token in .Net Core API?

Tags: rest, api, asp.net-core, .net-core, jwt

I'm using **.Net Core** for my API, so no views or whatsoever. I'm also using **ASP.net Core Identity** framework to authorize users in my database.
For logging in users, I use this code:

```
private string GenerateAuthenticationResult(ApplicationUser user)
        {
            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_jwtSettings.Secret);
            var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
            {
                // Things to be included and encoded in the token
                Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
                {
                    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.Email),
                    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
                    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email, user.Email),
                    new Claim("id", user.Id)
                }),
                // Token will expire 2 hours from which it was created
                Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(2),
                //
                SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
            };

            var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);

            return tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
        }
```

This works like a charm for authenticating user actions, but how can I know whom my server is talking to provided that the user used the token I provided earlier for logging in in his request header (Bearer).

**TL;dr**

I want to extract user ID or user Email from the token provided in the request header.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `AddJwtBearer` validating JWT tokens :

```
var sharedKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(
            Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("yourkey"));
services.AddAuthentication(x =>
{
    x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(x =>
{
    x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    x.SaveToken = true;

    x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = sharedKey,

        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidateAudience = false,
        ValidateLifetime = false,            
    };
});
```

And enable asp.net core authentication middleware via adding `app.UseAuthentication();` in `Configure` method . After that , you can add `[Authorize]` attribute on protected actions/controllers .

To get the email and user id after authentication in action :

```
var  email= User.Claims.Where(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.Email).FirstOrDefault()?.Value;
var  userid= User.Claims.Where(x => x.Type == "id").FirstOrDefault()?.Value;
```

Here  `ClaimTypes.Email` is used since `JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email` will map to `ClaimTypes.Email` by middleware automatically . See [source code](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/blob/dev/src/System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt/ClaimTypeMapping.cs#L54) .

Here are some useful articles for JWT Authentication :

https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/08/14/aspnet-core-21-jwt-authentication-tutorial-with-example-api

https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/10/11/aspnet-core-3-jwt-authentication-tutorial-with-example-api